# Retrofit Response in android returning null values

Tags: android, retrofit

I am working on an Android app using the Retrofit library and I can not access some fields that are returned by retrofit.

My JSON Structure is as follows:

```
{
    "contacts": [
        {
            "id": 19,
            "name": "some name",
            "phone_number": 12345678,
            "country": "some country",
            "age": 25
        }
    ]
}
```

My POJO class I created for the JSON Structure is as follows:

```
public class Contact {

@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private Integer id;
@SerializedName("name")
@Expose
private String name;
@SerializedName("phone_number")
@Expose
private Integer phoneNumber;
@SerializedName("country")
@Expose
private String country;
@SerializedName("age")
@Expose
private Integer age;

public Integer getId() {
return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
this.name = name;
}

public Integer getPhoneNumber() {
return phoneNumber;
}

public void setPhoneNumber(Integer phoneNumber) {
this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
}

public String getCountry() {
return country;
}

public void setCountry(String country) {
this.country = country;
}

public Integer getAge() {
return age;
}

public void setAge(Integer age) {
this.age = age;
}

}
```

and the class I call for the response:

```
public class Example {

@SerializedName("contacts")
@Expose
private List<Contact> contacts = null;

public List<Contact> getContacts() {
return contacts;
}

public void setContacts(List<Contact> contacts) {
this.contacts = contacts;
}

}
```

and when I try to access the fields using:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("" + GlobalVariables.BASE_URL)
            .client(client)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

BaseRestInterface request = retrofit.create(BaseRestInterface.class);
Call<Example > call = request.getContacts();
call.enqueue(new Callback<Example>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<Example> call, Response<Example> response) {
        loading.dismiss();
        assert response.body() != null;
        String name = response.body().getContacts().get(0).getName();
        int age = response.body().getContacts().get(0).getAge();
      



}

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<Example> call, Throwable t) {
        loading.dismiss();
        if(t instanceof IOException) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Connection Problem, Please Try Again Later",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT, true).show();
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), t.getMessage(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT, true).show();
        }
    }
});
```

I get a null value, is there anything I am doing wrong? I get the response when debugging my app, I just can not get the values

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you're calling `setContacts` after you receive the response?

Comment: Kindly post the full code of how you're handling the response.

Comment: I hve posted an edit to my code

Comment: The first rule of a network request is: have you inspected the network request with a proxy (like Chalres) or, have you managed to make this same network request using `curl` or Postman or any similar tool? Have you enabled Logging to see the network req.? are you using OkHttp, what does your interceptor show? etc.

Comment: @MartinMarconici Yes, I have enabled logging and got a correct response using OKHttp, but the problem is whenever I try to access the values as I mentioned above I get a null value.